# Formula to get most recent value for distinct ids in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to `Index` and `Match` functions.  I'm looking to get the most recent value for each id.  The dates are not sorted.  I'm trying to come up with a formula for the "Expected Values" column

[image]

Comment: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,E2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,E2))
```

[image]